# Java JUnit Testing

Tags: java, testing, junit

Chris has written a function called toBinary that has an input parameter of an integer number and returns a string that represents the binary equivalent. For example, if the function is called with the integer number 3 then the returned string should be '11'.

Write a sequence of test specifications in English possibly using the "given", "when", and "then" sequence and their equivalent JUnit code.

My answer is:

The test should cover normal cases, extreme cases, and erroneous cases. Given an integer for example 3, it should then covert it to 11 after the method is executed.

```
@Test
public void testToBinary() {
Binary aBinary = new Binary();
assertEquals(3, 11);
assertEquals(2, 10);
assertFail(10, 8575);
}
```

is this correct?

Comment: when you say that `toBinary` "has an input parameter of an integer", do you mean it takes an `int` or an `Integer`? There is no `integer` that I'm aware of. If it takes an `Integer`, is there well-defined behavior for the null case? If so, does it throw an NPE? If so, can you assert that an NPE is thrown?

Comment: I would also add cases for `Integer.MAX_VALUE` / `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 6):

Those asserts don't make sense -- of course, 3 != 11.  You'd need apply the conversion method to the input and verify that the output is expected:

```
assertEquals("11", aBinary.someConvertMethod(3));
```

The expected value must be the first parameter, and the actual value is the second parameter.

Also, assertFail isn't a real method.  There is assertNotEquals, that's probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

In your code sample, when you write 'assertEquals(3, 11);' You assert that 3 equals 11 (base ten) which will always be false.

Would you not require something like

```
assertEquals("11", toBinary(3));
```

Which tests that your function, given an input of three, returns the String "11".

Answer (score 1):

you can add testcases for zero and negative numbers..

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost each unit test should have at **most** one assert.  As others have stated you must invoke the constructor or whichever method you are relying on in the actual test case:
`assertEquals("11",toBinary(3);`